# My whole script is not working because of a deprecated mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is the line that is causing problems.

```
mysql_connect($dbhost ,$dbuser, $dbpass); mysql_select_db($dbname);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

I just got the code from codecanyon and I don't understand how to fix it. It says that it's deprecated

Comment: did u try the mysqli syntaxes?

Comment: Or PDO, both mysqli and PDO will require some re-toolling of the website.  Perhaps a bit less with mysqli but it is what it is.

Comment: The mysql_* functions are deprecated and should not be used.  You can replace them with the mysqli_* functions or with PDO.  No matter which way you go, you will have to change all your mysql functions once you change your database connection.  This may be the only error you are seeing now, but once you change those lines, others will cause errors until they are fixed as well.  As ArtisiticPhoenix mentioned, the mysqli_* functions would require less code rework, since the functions are more similar than their PDO counterparts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with example

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**
The entire ext/mysql PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0 and will be removed in the future.

It was originally introduced in PHP v2.0 (November 1997) for MySQL v3.20, and no new features have been added since 2006. Coupled with the lack of new features are difficulties in maintaining such old code amidst complex security vulnerabilities.

The manual has contained warnings against its use in new code since June 2011.
**To Fix:**
As the error message suggests, there are two other MySQL extensions that you can consider: MySQLi and PDO_MySQL, either of which can be used instead of ext/mysql. Both have been in PHP core since v5.0, so if you're using a version that is throwing these deprecation errors then you can almost certainly just start using them right away—i.e. without any installation effort.

They differ slightly, but offer a number of advantages over the old extension including API support for transactions, stored procedures and prepared statements (thereby providing the best way to defeat SQL injection attacks). PHP developer Ulf Wendel has written a thorough comparison of the features.

Hashphp.org has an excellent tutorial on migrating from ext/mysql to PDO.
I understand that it's possible to suppress deprecation errors by setting error_reporting in php.ini to exclude E_DEPRECATED:

error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED

But this is not the professional way of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Answer: Change mysql entries to 'mysqli'.

```
//Conect to server, now we specify the database in the connect request.
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost ,$dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf-8'");
$bstat = mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf-8');
...
mysqli_free_result($res);
...
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Not-so-quick Answer: mysql extension is obsolete, it has lots of security holes so PHP 5.5+ dropped support for this extension and further versions won't include it.

You should now use mysqli extension, which come in procedural and object-oriented flavors. Or migrate your code to PDO, which is more versatile.